# Is AlphaStar still competing in the Star Craft ladder?

Tags: gaming, deepmind

Last year it was announced that Deepmind's Starcraft playing bot AlphaStar was taking on human players in the Starcraft ladder system (some kind of league system as far as I can tell) and that it had reached the Grandmaster level.

Since then I haven't really heard anything anymore about the progress of Alphastar. Given that I don't know anything about Starcraft I was wondering whether somebody has a better clue as to what Alphastar is up to? Is it still playing online? Or when did it stop playing? What was the improvement trajectory during the time it played online? Basically, how did this pan out, as seen from the perspective of the Starcraft community?